# Closure inside interior under quotient map

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to show the following: given $A \subset B \subset X$ topological space. Assume $Cl(A) \subset Int(B)$. Let the quotient map $p: X \rightarrow X/A$. Show that $Cl(A/A) \subset Int(B/A)$. I have been trying to use the fact that for any continuous function $f$, $Cl(f^{-1}(E)) \subset f^{-1}(Cl(E))$, but $Cl(p^{-1}(A/A)) \subset p^{-1}(Cl(A/A))$, but what I need is the other direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can view it this way: for any quotient map $q: X \to Y$ we may call $A ⊆ X$ *saturated* if it is the $q$-preimage of some set $B ⊆ Y$. So we have a $1:1$ correspondence between subsets of $Y$ and saturated subsets of $X$. Having the quotient topology on $Y$ means that open sets are exactly those whose corresponding subsets of $X$ are open.

Now your particular quotient if quite simple – you just collapse $A$ to a point (if its nonempty), so every subset of $X$ that contains $A$ or misses $A$ is saturated. Now can you use these observations to prove your proposition?

Comment: Ah, so I need to show that $p^{-1}(Cl(A/A)) = Cl(A)$ and $Cl(A)$ is saturated, so $p(Cl(A)) = Cl(A/A)$ right?

Comment: Yes, and similarly for $\operatorname{int}(B)$.